# How to get the correct result in sql query?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I want to query through my `Membership` table to get the result for certain member but I am getting the wrong result. Here is my query:

```
  select MemNo, MemDOB, MemberType, MemShrBal
  From Membership
  Where MemberType = 1 or MemberType = 2 
  and MemDOB > '1973/12/31' 
  and MemShrBal = 250.00
```

Can anyone help me to find out why: besides proper *member* records I am also getting those *member* records with `MemShrBal` more than 250.0 and `MemDOB` below '1973'?

Comment: "When combining these conditions [AND / OR], it is important to use brackets so that the database knows what order to evaluate each condition."

Comment: yeah I was having some bracket problem..now its ok..thanks a lot for your answer..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need some brackets:

```
select MemNo, MemDOB, MemberType, MemShrBal
  From Membership
  Where (MemberType = 1 or MemberType = 2)
  and MemDOB > '1973/12/31' 
  and MemShrBal = 250.00
```

`and` binds more tightly than `or`, so without the brackets, it's

```
  MemberType = 1

  or
      MemberType = 2
      and MemDOB > '1973/12/31' 
      and MemShrBal = 250.00
```